# Generate auto number counter 0001 using vb.net 2015 and oracle 11g

Tags: vb.net, oracle, counter

i have a number 0001 now i need to + 1 like 0002, but vb.net 0001 + 1 = 2

```vb
newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

what i do for to resolve the problem

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way.  A number is a number.  If you need numbers then use numbers.  If you need to display a number with leading zeroes then you need to create a `String`, e.g. `Dim str = num.ToString("0000")`.

Comment: You really shouldn't be generating those numbers like that.  Just like SQL Server, Oracle supports both identities and sequences so you should be letting the database generate the values.  You should store those values as the numbers they are and then format as text when you need to display the leading zeroes.  If that's just in the application then you already know how to do that.  If you need that formatted text in the database too then add another column that generates its value based on the numeric column automatically.

Comment: What does Oracle have to do with this question? You appear to be doing this entirely in VB so Oracle is irrelevant.... if you are are asking how to modify it to use Oracle then use a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm).

Comment: i get the value from oracle 0001 by using cmd.ExecuteScalar() now i need to add +1  like 0001+ 1 = 0002 for this i used Dim newProdID As Int32 = 0 newProdID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) , then i get answer 2 but i want 0002, what i should do to get answer like 0002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, just use string format.

```vb
Dim i As Integer = 1
Dim s As String
i = i + 1
s = i.ToString("0000") ' output = 0002
```

or

```vb
(1 + 1).ToString("0000") ' output = 0002
```